# list is not getting displayed under onChangedof viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an activity where the details has been fetched from server...i have used retrofit with viewmodel...rest the details displayed but the inner horizontal recycleview is not getting displayed ...crashing while loading...

here is my activity code:---------

```
 model = ViewModelProvider(this)[ProductViewModel::class.java]
    model.ProductDetails?.observe(this, object : Observer<Product_base_response?> {
        override fun onChanged(t: Product_base_response?) {
            text.setText(t?.data?.name.toString())
            textcost.setText(t?.data?.cost.toString())
            text2.setText(t?.data?.producer.toString())
            descript.setText(t?.data?.description)
            myRatingBar.rating = rating.toFloat()
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(t?.data?.product_images?.get(0)?.image).into(
                    imagemain!!
                )
           //loading list here but crashing
            val retro11: List<Product_images_response>? =
                t?.data?.product_images
            //Log.e("kdjn",t?.data?.product_images!!.toString())
            generateDataList(retro11!!)
        }
        })

    model.loaddetails(id.toString())
    
}
    fun generateDataList(dataList: List<Product_images_response>) {
        val recyclerView=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.Recycleviewdetails)
        val adapter =Custom_detail_Adapter(applicationContext, dataList)
        recyclerView.adapter=adapter
        val linear:LinearLayoutManager=
            LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        recyclerView.layoutManager=linear
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    }
```

viewmodel:----(not displaying full code just relevant one)

```
   fun loaddetails(product_id:String)
{
    RetrofitClient.instance.fetchUserdetail(product_id)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<Product_base_response> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Product_base_response>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("res", "" + t)

            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Product_base_response>,
                response: Response<Product_base_response>
            ) {

                _productDetails!!.value = response.body()

            }
        })
```

adapter:-=------

```
class  Custom_detail_Adapter(
context: Context,
dataList: List<Product_images_response>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<Custom_detail_Adapter.CustomViewHolder>() {
private val dataList: List<Product_images_response>
private val context: Context

private var selectedPos: Int = 0

inner class CustomViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val mView: View

     val avatar: ImageView
    val relativeitem:RelativeLayout

    init {
        mView = itemView

        avatar = mView.findViewById(R.id.view3)
         relativeitem=mView.findViewById(R.id.relativeitem)

        }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail_item, parent, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
  ///  holder.relativeitem.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    holder.relativeitem.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
 Glide.with(context).load(dataList[position].image)
        .thumbnail(0.5f)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(holder.avatar)


    holder.avatar.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
            selectedPos = position
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)

        val intent = Intent("custom-message")
        intent.putExtra("item", dataList.get(position).image)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)
    })
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size }

init {
    this.context = context
    this.dataList = dataList
}
}
```

but I'm getting a array response under logcat

on debuging this line -->                 `Log.e("kdjn",t?.data?.product_images.toString())`

```
[Product_images_response(id=39, product_id=13, image=http:/2.jpg, created=2015-09-14T10:18:23+0000, modified=2015-09-14T10:18:23+0000), Product_images_response(id=40, product_id=13, image=7.jpg, created=2015-09-14T10:21:38+0000, modified=2015-09-14T10:21:38+0000), Product_images_response(id=41, product_id=13, image=http://9.jpg, created=2015-09-14T10:22:09+0000, modified=2015-09-14T10:22:09+0000), Product_images_response(id=42, product_id=13, image=http://1.jpg, created=2015-09-14T10:22:59+0000, modified=2015-09-14T10:22:59+0000)]
```

Comment: Please, put the error from Logcat.

Comment: please dont mark as duplicate as null pointer error im getting ...need help...here im getting in log --> ` kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.xxxx.ProductDetails.Productdetails$onCreate$2.onChanged(Productdetails.kt:164)` @ManuelMato

Comment: im not getting why is it displaying null where in normal retrofit method(without viewmodel implementation) i could able to fetch that list @ManuelMato

Comment: What is exactly your line 164 on Productdetails.kt ?? because you have this commented code //loading list here but crashing but is not possible because you have a log, so please, share the right line to see what is crashing.  Another thing, this code is a bad code generateDataList(retro11!!) because you said that retro11 is nullable, you don´t verify if is nullbar but you is sure that is not null, what? A possible solution is: retro11?.let { generateDataList(it) } and you are using architecture but your architecture has a bad implementation.

Comment: @IRONMAN Please share entire error log which will be helpful determining root cause.